SwiftUI view adding trailing and leading icons
What would be the code to add leading and trailing icons to the swift UI view, which I display with the view controller, as displayed on the picture with the close icon and the Clear button?
Is this a built-in behavior, or a custom stack view? Can this be made sticky to the top, so that it would overlay the content if it gets scrolled?

Here is my code for the view:
struct CustomSheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    @State private var isNewInMenuSelected = false
    @State private var isOurFavoritesSelected = false
    @State private var isCustomerPickSelected = false

    var filtersLabel: String
    var useOurSearchFiltersLabel: String
    var applyFiltersLabel: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            Text(filtersLabel)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding(.top, 20)
                .padding(.leading, 20)

            Text(useOurSearchFiltersLabel)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .padding(.leading, 20)

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                Toggle("New in menu", isOn: $isNewInMenuSelected)
                Toggle("Our favorites", isOn: $isOurFavoritesSelected)
                Toggle("Customer pick", isOn: $isCustomerPickSelected)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)

            Spacer()

            Button(action: {
                let checkboxStates = [
                    "new_in_menu": isNewInMenuSelected,
                    "our_favorites": isOurFavoritesSelected,
                    "customer_pick": isCustomerPickSelected
                ]

                let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
                    .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
                    .compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }
                    .flatMap { $0.windows }
                    .first { $0.isKeyWindow }

                if let flutterViewController = keyWindow?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController {
                    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "custom_sheet_channel", binaryMessenger: flutterViewController.binaryMessenger)
                    channel.invokeMethod("checkboxStates", arguments: checkboxStates) { result in
                        // Handle any response if necessary
                    }
                }

                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text(applyFiltersLabel)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color(hex: "#d0a771"))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading) // Align content to top-left
    }
}


I assume this question is about implementing a header for a view shown as a .sheet.
Here are two techniques you can use:
1. Add a toolbar
You can apply a toolbar to the sheet content. This means nesting the sheet content inside some kind of container that supports a toolbar, for example, a NavigationStack:
struct SimpleSheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                Color.red.frame(height: 200)
                Color.orange.frame(height: 200)
                Color.yellow.frame(height: 200)
                Color.green.frame(height: 200)
                Color.blue.frame(height: 200)
                Color.indigo.frame(height: 200)
                Color.purple.frame(height: 200)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Filters")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                        dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .foregroundStyle(.foreground)
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Clear") {}
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundStyle(.green)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

When the main content is scrolled, it goes behind the toolbar and the toolbar automatically takes on a translucent background:

2. A custom header
If you don't especially need the translucent effect behind the header, then it is simple to build a custom header with a plain background.

Show the header as the first item in a VStack, with the scrolled region below it.

Use an HStack to combine the two buttons, with a Spacer between them. Then use a ZStack to combine the buttons with the title. This way, the title is always centered, both horizontally and vertically.


var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        ZStack {
            Text("Filters")
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
            HStack {
                Button {
                    dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundStyle(.foreground)
                }
                Spacer()
                Button("Clear") {}
                    .buttonStyle(.plain)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundStyle(.green)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
        ScrollView {
            // ...
        }
    }
}



Love it! Thanks a lot, @benzy neez
